# Unity - shadows not showing in WebGL / Game view only?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webgl, shadow, unity-webgl

I have an issue wherein on in game view in WebGL only, shadows do not show. In the scene view (also on WebGL), they do show. So far I have checked:

- Quality settings
- Lighting settings
- Confirmed the mesh and the material on the mesh are set to receive shadows

Specifically what could be causing this discrepancy? Shadows show up on all other targets where I've kept the quality settings the same across.

Comment: Could you try to describe some more details that could help? Like current code, a screenshot, or anything else that might help?

Comment: Well in editor you have the power of your machine, on the web you have a much cut down version of capabilities, however, webgl does indeed do shadows.. all my games are webgl and the difference between published and in editor is a lot. Some pictures of settings and output and editor would help

Comment: Resolved - it was the shadow distance

Comment: if this is resolved post a reply and mark it as the solution